# vue draggable problem when fix first column i can't move column

Tags: vue.js

vue draggable problem when fix first column i can't move column how i can solve this problem

I have a table of 4  columns, one column has a static list of values ​​and the next column I need to be draggable so that I can move the cells in the second column etc without affecting the first column.

```js
<script>
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
    export default {
        name: "table-column-example",
        components: {
            draggable
        },
        data() {
            return {
                headers: ["id", "name", "sport"],
                list: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Abby", sport: "basket" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Brooke", sport: "foot" },
                    { id: 3, name: "Courtenay", sport: "volley" },
                    { id: 4, name: "David", sport: "rugby" }
                ],
                dragging: false
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
    .ghost {
        opacity: 0.5;
        background: #fb1b27;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h3>Draggable table</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <draggable  :list="headers"  v-model="headers" :options="{draggable:'.item'}"  tag="tr">
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th class="item" v-for="header in headers" :key="header" scope="col">
                        {{ header }}
                    </th>
                </draggable>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.name">
                    <td>dddddd</td>
                    <td v-for="header in headers" :key="header">{{ item[header] }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You have provided a good snippet, so far so good. However, it is not so clear what you want: Is it about having only the first column (`id`) static and the rest (`name`, `sport`) draggable?

Comment: yes i want make first column static and other columns can movable
first colunm is static and first cell is # 
as this
a b| c|      #
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
when i do that other columns won't move why ??